# -[NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, unrecognized-selector

I have the next problem with this code:

```
NSDictionary * imagen = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[envio resultValue]];
NSString *imagenS = [imagen valueForKey:@"/Result"];

[Base64 initialize];
NSData * imagenDecode = [Base64 decode:imagenS];

NSLog(@"%@", [imagenS length]);

//SAVE IMAGE

NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@david.png",docDirectory]; 

[imagenDecode writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

**[envio resultValue] -->** return a NSDictionary with one image in Base 64 codification.

I want decoder and save this image but in my console I have showed this message:

```
2011-08-23 20:15:36.539 WSStub[39226:a0f] -[NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd00ee0
```

The Base 64 code is:

```
//
//  Base64.m
//  CryptTest
//
//  Created by Kiichi Takeuchi on 4/20/10.
//  Copyright 2010 ObjectGraph LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Base64.h"


@implementation Base64

#define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

static char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
static char decodingTable[128];

+ (void) initialize 
{
    if (self == [Base64 class]) 
    {
        memset(decodingTable, 0, ArrayLength(decodingTable));
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ArrayLength(encodingTable); i++) {
            decodingTable[encodingTable[i]] = i;
        }
    }
}


+ (NSData*) decode:(const char*) string length:(NSInteger) inputLength 
{
    if ((string == NULL) || (inputLength % 4 != 0)) 
    {
        return nil;
    }

    while (inputLength > 0 && string[inputLength - 1] == '=') 
    {
        inputLength--;
    }

    NSInteger outputLength = inputLength * 3 / 4;
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:outputLength];
    uint8_t* output = data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger inputPoint = 0;
    NSInteger outputPoint = 0;
    while (inputPoint < inputLength) 
    {
        char i0 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i1 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i2 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A'; /* 'A' will decode to \0 */
        char i3 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A';

        output[outputPoint++] = (decodingTable[i0] << 2) | (decodingTable[i1] >> 4);
        if (outputPoint < outputLength)
        {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i1] & 0xf) << 4) | (decodingTable[i2] >> 2);
        }
        if (outputPoint < outputLength)
        {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i2] & 0x3) << 6) | decodingTable[i3];
        }
    }

    return data;
}

+ (NSData*) decode:(NSString*) string 
{
    return [self decode:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] length:[string length]];
}

@end
```

Comment: It looks like `imagenS` is a `NSDictionary` and not a `NSString`. Can you post the result of logging `imagen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
NSString *imagenS = [imagen valueForKey:@"/Result"];
```

is returning a dictionary, not a string.  You'll have to inspect your data source to determine whether this is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Your NSLog() call is wrong. To show a length, it should be:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", [imagenS length]);
```

But that is probably not the problem.

You seem to be invoking `length` on an `NSDictionary`. Hard to tell where you do that, since you don't show the piece of code where that happens. It could be that `imagenS` is not an `NSString`, but an `NSDictionary` instead.

Try to do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [imagenS class]);
```

and see what is displayed. If probably tells you that `imagenS` is not a string, but an `NSCFDictionary` or similar instead.

---

FWIW, `NSCFDictionary` is one of the subclasses of `NSDictionary` that actually implement the different versions of the main class. This is called a class cluster.

Comment: This line provoke the error:  NSLog(@"%@", [imagenS length]);

Comment: Are you sure that the value returned by `[imagen valueForKey:@"/Result"]` is an NSString?

Comment: @Chaitanya: I guess he can be pretty sure that imagenS is **not** a string. <g>

Comment: @David: what happens if you do: `NSLog(@"%@", [imagenS class]);`?